# Using Google Apps Script to Add Custom Playlist Cover Image for Spotify Playlist

Tags: google-apps-script, spotify

I am trying to use the "Add Custom Playlist Cover Image" endpoint in the Spotify API. I have seen multiple questions on this for different languages but never a Google Apps Script example. I am quite sure that access and scope is in order, but I still get this reply back:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "status" : 401,
    "message" : "Unauthorized."
  }
}
```

Below you can see my code. I would appreciate a hint on what is wrong, or - even better - a snip of code from a working example.

```
  imageid = '1B6I3kol0UeEWLtpNUyKmj3e6B9DEQ2hy'
  
  var imageBytes = DriveApp.getFileById(imageid).getBlob().getBytes();
  var imageEncoded = Utilities.base64Encode(imageBytes);

  url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/' + id +'/images'
  
  var options = {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken(),
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
      },
    payload: imageEncoded
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in the logs? Because I can see that you're using an ```id``` variable here, which is never initialized (it's called ```imageid``` above).

Comment: Thanks, rob_med, but that is not the problem. The ID is initialized further up in the code.